# Input text inside a link tag in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-browser-mode

Is there a way to make input text inside a link tag works well in IE8? I cannot place the caret inside nor select the text within it.

```
<a href="#"><input type="text"></a>
```

I think the reason why I'm trying to do this is not important here, just consider I have no choice of make it work under an `<a>` tag. I only have control over what's inside the `<a>` tag.

As a solution, I was thinking about some JQuery DOM manipulation when in IE8 mode but there must be a easier/cleaner way of fixing this "bug".

Thanks

Comment: I think you can not place an input field within an `a` tag.

Comment: It works under ie9, firefox, chrome. So maybe it's just a standard IE8 doesn't respect again.

Comment: For those you want more information. This is because I'm using angular ui-bootstrap and tab heading are inside A tags. But I need to show a input text inside the tabs instead of simple text.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the input and link tag display properties, while an input is `display:inline-block;` your link is `display:inline;`. Try to play with these properties and z-index if it's not working.

Hovever, i think jQuery solution is better, and simpler, except if this is your only usage of jQuery on your page.

**HTML :**

```
<a href="#" id="myInputLink"><input type="text" /></a>
```

**jQuery script**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myInputLink").click(function(){
        // .trigger('focus') or .focus(), but the first one is better on my own
        $(this).next('input[type="text"]').trigger('focus');
    });
});
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for you time but both the solutions doesn't seems to works on IE8. Even with a focus() forced, it still doesn't let me place the cursor inside the input textbox. Also having 2 id with the same value is invalid in css.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to delete the second id on input.

Comment: Can you try to share your code in a jsfiddle or whatever ? Just an extract to have a better view of your problem

Comment: It won't be possible since IE8 doesn't work support nor plunkr and fiddle. But it's quite easy to test it on your side. Just create a simple HTML page and just do: <a href=""><input type="text"></a>